# Drilled vertically through LVL

Tags: framing, structural, load-bearing

I made an absolute fool of myself and drilled a 3/4" hole vertically through Laminated Veneer Lumber (LVL) when trying to run wires into an attic above an 30" wide exterior window. I realized my mistake after drilling through about ten (!) inches of material (not including the 2x4 the LVL sits on).

Here's a schematic of the exterior wall I'm working on:

[image]

The window in orange text is where the LVL is located. The wall this window is located has brick veneer siding.

Here's a view from the attic - the top plate that is outlined is where the LVL is located. The hole (if I went all the way through) would be at the text near the top of the outline. To the left of the top plate, you may be able to see a bit of the tar paper that's behind the brick veneer.

[image]

Here's an image of the exterior window in question:

[image]

I'm trying to determine what sort of load may be displaced due to drilling through the LVL. I intend on contacting a structural engineer for an assessment. At the very least, the roof won't collapse, but going almost entirely through a structural member is no good.

Comment: just for understanding can you spell the TLA

Comment: @Ruskes Sorry, I don't follow. The TLA?

Comment: Anybody trying to answer this question would know what an lvl is.

Comment: TLA = Three Letter Acronym.  Answerers might know but others trying to learn new things here might not.

Comment: I think you are OK with just q 3/4" hole.

Comment: Well how big is the LVL?

Comment: @Huesmann The LVL spans the width of the window opening, so 30". I want to say it's 10 or 12 inches thick.

Comment: Do you know the width of the lvl? (And, @Gal — you’re right.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate The wall opposite of this exterior wall is using two LVLs with an OSB in-between to fill out the 2x4 wall cavity, so it should be 2".